# Oracle APEX Interactive Report Having Clause

Tags: oracle, report, oracle-apex, interactive

Is it possible to add a filter with a having clause in an interactive report ?
for eg. if I use the interactive report's Data => Aggregate function. I would like to further refine my results with a having clause on the aggregated value like `sum(column_name) > 100`

APEX Version: 20.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, not possible through Interactive Report's "Action" menu.

Workaround (if you think it'll help) is to modify report's query by adding the `SUM` function in its analytic form, e.g.

```
select empno,
       ename,
       sal,
       --
       sum(sal) over (partition by empno) sumsal       --> this
from ...
```

Now you'd be able to include newly added `sumsal` column into Interactive Report's filter: `sumsal > 100`

Comment: Thank You very for the suggestion. This may work for a few of my scenarios.